# How to add "and !=" in ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to add one more condition with `AND` and `!=` in this query
(i.e.: and properties.property_type_id != 'NULL')

How to add in this active record?

```
@properties = Property.where(category_id: Admin
  .select("category_id").where(id: current_user.id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@properties = Property.where("category_id IN (?) AND property_type_id IS NOT NULL", Admin.where(id: current_user.id).map(&:category_id) )
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Happy to help... you may wish to select as right answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hello 'and' query is adding a where condition to the query.

```html
@properties = Property.where(category_id: Admin.select("category_id").where(id: current_user.id)).where('property_type_id is NOT NULL')
```

Comment: hai, please try this also and tell me whether it works? for my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You initially need to map all category_ids

```
category_ids = Admin.where(:id => current_user.id).map(&:category_id)
```

This will return all category_ids you need.

Now you fetch the desired result from the property table.

```
@properties = Property.where("category_id IN (?) AND property_type_id IS NOT NULL",category_ids)
```

Comment: this too works :), thank you for all who helped me :)